# What is the correct inverse function for $f(x) = x^2$. Question about terminology.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology, real-numbers

Is the inverse function $g_1(x)=\sqrt{x}$ or is it $g_2(x)=-\sqrt{x}$. With what terminology can we describe both of these functions?

Comment: It seems like neither of them inverts it in any way, $g_1(f(x))= \sqrt {x^4}$ do you mean $g_1(x)=\sqrt x$?

Comment: No inverse this function in the whole real since it is not injective on $\Bbb R$ .

Comment: I think what 00GB is trying to say is that "the inverse" is meaningless, as the function is not invertible on the real number line. Have you heard of the *horizontal line test*?

Comment: @razivo Yes I made a mistake there

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is where a function is defined, if we say $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,f(x)= x^2$
then there isn't an inverse since $x^2$ isn't bijective from $\mathbb R $
to $\mathbb R$.($f(1)=f(-1)$)
if we see it as a function from $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R^+$ it is bijective and thus has an inverse, namely, the normal positive square root function $\sqrt x$.
if we see it as a function from $\mathbb R^-$ to $\mathbb R^+$ it is also bijective and thus has an inverse, namely, the negative square root function $-\sqrt x$.
the problems stems from that for any $x$, $x^2 = (-x)^2$ and thus the function can't be bijective of the entire plane.